# How can I make VoiceOver skip <button> elements?

Tags: html, accessibility, voiceover

I use VoiceOver/Chrome on a iPad to test whether accessibility works on a page I am developing. I connect a Bluetooth keyboard to the iPad and click on the Tab key to go through elements on the page. This page has a button

```
<button name="next" aria-labelledby="next-page-hint" tabindex="0" role="button" role="button">Next</button>
```

However, VoiceOver skips the button without stopping on it.

This is the HTML page used in the test

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

  <form>

    <div tabindex="0" role="text">this is the beginning</div>

    <div>-----------------------</div>

    <button name="next1" aria-labelledby="next-page-hint" tabindex="0" role="button" >Next 1</button>

    <div>-----------------------</div>

    <button name="next2">Next 2</button>

    <div>-----------------------</div>

    <h2 id="lbl">Men's Outerwear</h2>
    <button id="btn" aria-labelledby="lbl btn">Shop Now</button>

    <div>-----------------------</div>

    <h2 id="lbl">Men's Outerwear 2</h2>
    <button id="btn">Shop Now 2</button>

    <div>-----------------------</div>

    <div tabindex="0" role="text">this is the end</div>

  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

When I use the Tab key to go through this page, VoiceOver only discovers and pronounces "This is the beginning" and "This is the end".

**UPDATE 2**

I was able to tab through all buttons with the left/swipe gestures. The problem is to use **the Tab key on a keyboard** to tab through the buttons. The ios on the iPad is 15.4.1.

If I put the following textbox in the form, the VoiceOver is able to pronounce it correctly with the tab key tabbing through the elements on the page.

```
<textarea name="ta">This is textarea</textarea>
```

**Update 3**

The following code is what I tested and it seems to be working without changing accessibilities settings @slugolicious suggested (Thank you!).
Maybe we can call it a workaround?

```
<div>
  <div class="radio" tabindex="0">
    <label for="q1015678-2430294-button21">
      <input type="radio" name="ddd1" value="0" id="q1015678-2430294-button21"> <span>Good</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio" tabindex="0">
    <label for="q1015678-2430295-button21" >
      <input type="radio" name="ddd1" value="1" id="q1015678-2430295-button21"> <span>Bad</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this needs more context. That button definitely should be included in the tab order if it's coded like that (and both the `tabindex=0` and `role="button"` are completely unnecessary/redundant for an HTML button). I guess either you have an unusual DOM order which means the button doesn't appear in the place it might be expected in the tab order, or some Javascript is messing with the tabbing. Or perhaps something else - but useless speculating without being able to reproduce the problem!

Comment: Thanks for chiming in! I updated the post. VoiceOver is unable to find any of the buttons on the page. Hope that I didn't anything wrong.

Comment: I tested your HTML using Chrome and VoiceOver on iOS 15 and VoiceOver announces all the buttons on the page correctly. Not sure whether using a Bluetooth keyboard would change VoiceOver behaviour at all (I'm assuming it wouldn't) but it works fine with the left/right swipe gestures to tab through each of the page elements.

Comment: @George thanks for your input. VoiceOver is working with left/right swipe gestures in my tests too. The problem I have is to use the Tab key to tab through the elements. Were you able to tab through with the Tab key?

Comment: @curious1 Unfortunately I don't have a Bluetooth keyboard to connect to my iOS device, else I'd test it for you.

Comment: You're right. I tried a BT keyboard with my iPhone and Safari and the TAB key skips over the buttons.  I can navigate with the rotor to all the buttons just fine.

Comment: @slugolicious, thanks for confirming this issue. It would be really unbelievable and disappointing that this is a bug considering Apple's engineering strength and such a simple test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *"feels"* like the Mac issue where the TAB key doesn't go to all elements unless you intentionally enable it in system preferences > keyboard and select "all controls" for keyboard access.

On the iPhone/iPad you can go into Settings > Accessibility > Keyboards > Full Keyboard Access and enable the "Full Keyboard Access" switch.  This allows the <kbd>TAB</kbd> on the bluetooth keyboard to navigate to all buttons.

Seems stupid to have to do that and it makes Voiceover harder to use when it's enabled but it **is** possible.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your info! I updated my post with a workaround solution. Not elegant, but seems working. However, I still selected yours as the solution.  Would you mind seeing whether the workaround works for you? I got it through  numerous tests myself.

Comment: Your "update 3" is using radio buttons now instead of simple buttons so that doesn't seem like a workaround.  They're different types of form elements. Plus you have a tabindex=0 on a `<div>` but the div itself is not an interactive element nor does it have a role so that will be confusing for screen reader users.